# How to handle MediaPlayer object inside a fragment inside view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, audio, android-viewpager

I have viewpager which holds fragments, each fragment is having MediaPlayer object i.e each fragment is having audio attached to it. My requirement is if i swipe the viewpager,current fragment media player should stop and next fragment media player should play. If i swipe viewpager backwards then current fragment media player should stop and previous fragment media player should start. It is not necessary that each fragment should have a audio attached to it so thats why each fragment is having own media player object and i have put the check for audio to handle it. so far i have tried below code

In each fragment is having a visibility check and play the audio accordingly,

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            if (mPlayer != null ) {
                mPlayer.start();
            }
        } else {
            if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.pause();
                mPlayer.seekTo(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

If i release media player object in OnStop of fragment then audio stop working if i comes again to same fragment.

```
  @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.reset(); // Might not be necessary, since release() is called right after, but it doesn't seem to hurt/cause issues
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
```

How to resolve this ? I dont know how to control media player inside fragment of a viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to override onPause() and onResume() in fragment. And we need to save the current position for media player. So, I am using the shared preference to save the position for media player.
In `onCreateView, mediaPlayer_position = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PLAY_PAUSE", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("CHECK_PLAY_PAUSE", 0);`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int position = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PLAY_PAUSE", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("CHECK_PLAY_PAUSE", 0);
    if(position > 0) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mp3_link); //mp3_link from url to mediaplayer data source
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaPlayer.seekTo(position);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer_position = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PLAY_PAUSE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("CHECK_PLAY_PAUSE", mediaPlayer_position).apply();
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }  
}
```

Ref: "https://www.hrupin.com/2011/02/example-of-streaming-mp3-mediafile-with-android-mediaplayer-class"